# How to remove rows of NaNs without losing my indices?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter, nan

I have a dataframe that came from a dataset with hierarchical indexing/multi-indexing. I believe I have correctly set the index, using the 3 columns, by using df.set_index.

However, now I have NaNs remaining in my first two rows.

[df with NaNs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LZCGl.png)

I would like to get rid of these and just have the first row read as

Under 25 years | Both sexes | State | 20877 | ..., etc.

like this (done in Markdown - but without the dots, just added them as it wouldn't render with blank cells)

[aim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoaoD.png)

I have tried using df.drop, df.dropna, and deleting the row but not the first column, i.e. the index, but nothing seems to be working the way I need it to.

Using df.dropna() results in the following, and as you can see my Under 25 years and Both Sexes that were indices, are now missing too.

Any help would be appreciated!

[missing indices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4mUt.png)

Comment: Why don't you get rid of these NAs before setting the indexes? Like: `df.dropna(subset=[colB, colC]).set_index(['colA','colB','colC'])`.

Comment: @CainãMaxCouto-Silva when I do it this way I still get the same issue, unfortunately :( (I tried attaching another picture, but I cannot, but it gives the same issue as my last image above)

Comment: Did you delete your question about this yesterday?

Comment: I see... but seems like you don't have any info for "both_sexes" at all. If that's the case, your manually created aim output isn't correct because you're attributing values from another category from the "Sex" column (and empty one, maybe?) to both sexes.

Look at the State followed by the value 20877 for example. It does not belong to "Both sexes" in your original data, and you've filled it in the same row from "Both sexes" at the second pic.

Comment: @JAV Yes. It was marked as closed. It suggested that I delete it and post one with more information. So I did.

Comment: @CainãMaxCouto-Silva Hmm, I see what you mean here. The original data is grouped by Age, then Sex, then Area. So it looks at Under 25 years, Both Sexes, then goes through all of the Areas. Next it looks at Under 25 years, Male, then goes through all of the areas, and so on. So I assumed it would be possible to get the dataframe to appear as in my markdown table.